# With Visual Studio App Center (Hockeyapp?) can I have a user email me their crash log or identify themselves so I can find their specific crash?

Tags: hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

Say a user is getting a really annoying crash and with their permission I want to help them and fix it. But also say I have a ton of other users also experiencing crashes so their specific crash is hard to identify.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/ios#identify-installations

How can I (with their permission) pull their crash log out? I know each install has an anonymous Installation ID or whatever, if I make theirs visible in the app, is there a way to have them email that to me so I can search crash reports based on that? Or is there a way to just straight up have them email me their crash report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by attaching a user's ID to the crash reports in App Center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/ios#identify-users

This can either be the ID from your own account system or you can for example just re-use the anonymous Installation ID generated by the App Center SDK for this. Then, you would also need a way for the user to tell you their ID, either by surfacing it in the UI, by automatically attaching it to a support request, or similar.

Afterwards, you can use App Center's search functionality to search for crashes by that ID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/search